# Advantage of flexible cutting mat?

Tags: equipment

For anyone who owns and uses a flexible cutting mat, what do you enjoy about it?
Thanks

Comment: Howdy!  This question explicitly asks for opinions, which is off-topic per the site guide: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask  Please change the question to make it possible to answer it with facts and citations.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I can cut/chop ingredients then curve the mat to transfer them to a pan/container without spillage ...

They also take up less space and I have four colour code mats for meat, fish, vegetables, and fruit.

Comment: Yep, those are basically the main advantages of why I use them.  And being plastic, they can go through the dishwasher, so I'd pull one out and place it on my wooden cutting board when dealing with meat.  (or fish, but I don't cook that very often)

Comment: Oh, and some of them have a hole in them -- so I can hang them on the side of a cabinet, so they're easy to grab when I need them.  (I use have 3 sets at this point that I rotate through ... the set without holes hardly ever gets used)